# Force relayout of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a situation where recycled views are displayed but, I presume due to some optimization in Android, they do not relayout.

A number of posts suggest calling view.layout() on the recycled view, which I suspect will work.  However, it also means setting up my own LayoutParams and, while I'm pretty sure I can get it to work, I don't really have all the info available at that point where the recycled view is reinitiailzed to do it properly.

This problem might be unique to having nested LinearLayouts.  When I ran a test, by collapsing to a single LinearLayout, the problem disappeared.

Here's a simplified version of the layout which fails.  In this example, the outer LinearLayout's onLayout() is called.  I don't know (without more experimentation) if the inner layout's onLayout() is called.  The TextView's onLayout is not called nor for "other stuff".

UPDATE: the inner layout's onLayout() is not being called.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/node"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/note"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

    ... more stuff ...
  </LinearLayout>

  ... more stuff ...

</LinearLayout >
```

Oh, I should mention this appears to be happening only on devices running Android API 19.

I'm hoping there's a "proper" way to force Android to relayout the the TextView and other widgets at its level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the member function forceLayout(), which I employed in the following recursive function.  It didn't seem to add any significant runtime overhead to my app.

```
  public static void forceLayoutAndroid19 (ViewGroup vg)
  {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {
      for (int i = 0, limit = vg.getChildCount ();  i < limit;  i++)
      {
        View child = vg.getChildAt (i);
        child.forceLayout ();
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup)
          forceLayoutAndroid19 ((ViewGroup)child);
      }
    }
  }
```